# Como configurar o GitHub no Visual Studio 2013 (Compartilhar projeto na rede Local)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, github

Como configurar o GitHub (Version 2.26) no Visual Studio 2013 (no VST 2013 em Solution Explorer/Team Explorer) para compartilhar um projeto na Rede local?

Comment: Veja se isso ajuda: http://michaelcrump.net/setting-up-github-to-work-with-visual-studio-2013-step-by-step/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O GitHub é um serviço de hospedagem, você não irá configurá-lo no Visual Studio! O que você tem que fazer é clonar o repositório e depois fazer o push para o GitHub.

1. Clique em Connect to Team Projects
   [image: Connect to Team Project]
2. Clique em Clone

[image: Clique em Clone]

Siga o processo normal do Git... Se você não tem experiência com Git eu escrevi um post [Git básico…para quem está vindo do TFVC, ou Source Safe, ou SVN](http://egomesbrandao.com.br/2015/03/git-bsicopara-quem-est-vindo-do-tfvc-ou-source-safe-ou-svn/), tem 3 partes.

Comment: Muito obrigado Brandão! Vou Estudar teu post, realmente não tenho experiencia com o Git!